# How to add JerseyJaxrsConfig class to grizzly as servlet

Tags: java, grizzly, swagger

I am working on implementing [Swagger](https://developers.helloreverb.com/swagger/) to generate API documentation.  I'm following the configuration guide here: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart but it's all XML based, and when I try to do what I believe in the equivalent in runtime configuration Grizzly complains - `Cannot resolve method 'addServlet(java.lang.String, com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig)'`.

It seems to be that `JerseyJaxrsConfig extends HttpServlet` instead of `Servlet`.  Any suggestions on what I can do?

```
public class Main {

    public static final URI BASE_URI = getBaseURI();

    public static final String API_VERSION = "0.1.0";

    private static URI getBaseURI() {
        return UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost/").port(9998).build();
    }

    protected static HttpServer startServer() throws IOException {
        ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("com.my.package.api.resources", "com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing");
        rc.getFeatures()
            .put(JSONConfiguration.FEATURE_POJO_MAPPING, true);

        return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        //System.setProperty("java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter.format", "%4$s: %5$s%n");

        System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false"); //avoid unrecognized_name during SSL handshake with deconet

        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext annotationCtx = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(Config.class);

        //add API documentation
        WebappContext ctx = new WebappContext("Documentation", "/docs");
        ServletRegistration swaggerServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyJaxrsConfig", new com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig());
        swaggerServletRegistration.setInitParameter("api.version", API_VERSION);
        swaggerServletRegistration.setInitParameter("swagger.api.basepath", BASE_URI.toString());
        swaggerServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(2);
        swaggerServletRegistration.addMapping("/*");

        HttpServer httpServer = startServer();

        System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at " + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI, BASE_URI));
        System.in.read();
        httpServer.stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: HttpServlet implements Servlet (via GenericServlet), so it shouldn't be a problem. Is it compile-time problem? IMO

ServletRegistration swaggerServletRegistration = ctx.addServlet("JerseyJaxrsConfig", com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig.class);

would be a better equivalent.

Comment: @alexey - Right, but the issue is that `JerseyJaxrsConfig extends Servlet` and doesn't `implement HttpServlet`

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem. Can you pls. create and share the testcase (maven based project would be great)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going about it the wrong way. JerseyJaxrsConfig is a hack to pass in config params to Swagger, statically. You can just do something like this in startServer()

```
ServletConfig sc = new MyServletConfig();
JerseyJaxrsConfig jjc = new JerseyJaxrsConfig();
jjc.init(sc);

return GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer(BASE_URI, rc);
```

Here's a sample MyServletConfig class (I use an inner class on Main):

```
private static class MyServletConfig implements ServletConfig {
    private Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<>();

    private MyServletConfig() {
        initParams.put("api.version", "1.0.0");
        initParams.put("swagger.api.basepath", "http://localhost:8080/content-store");
    }

    @Override
    public String getServletName() {
        return "JaxRS Servlet";
    }

    @Override
    public ServletContext getServletContext() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getInitParameter(String s) {
        return initParams.get(s);
    }

    @Override
    public Enumeration getInitParameterNames() {
        return Collections.enumeration(initParams.keySet());
    }
}
```

I frankly have no clue about most of what you are doing in main(String[]), but if you were trying to mock a web context to pass on those values to Swagger, drop the code. Mine looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    final HttpServer server = startServer();
    System.out.println(String.format("Jersey app started with WADL available at "
            + "%sapplication.wadl\nHit enter to stop it...", BASE_URI));
    System.in.read();
    server.stop();
}
```

All that being said, this is an alternative way of doing it:

```
ConfigFactory.config().setBasePath("http://localhost:8080/content-store");
```

It basically does the same thing; I also wanted to customize other things that are more Jersey specific so I kept using the JerseyJaxrsConfig class, so I used the first incantation, but your mileage may vary.

Hope that helps!