# Setup Swagger for Jersey fails due to missing JerseyJaxrsConfig class

Tags: jersey, classnotfoundexception, swagger

I want to setup Swagger for Jersey REST API documentation and so I followed this guide on github: https://github.com/wordnik/swagger-core/wiki/Java-JAXRS-Quickstart

I added the following to my Pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
<artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10</artifactId>
<version>1.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

After saving this file, maven downloaded the following jars which seems to be correct:

- swagger-jersey-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.0.jar
- swagger-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.0.jar
- swagger-core_2.10-1.3.0.jar

Then I am able to create some annotation with @Api, @ApiOperation, and so on. But the configuration is not finished yet.

In my Web.xml i need to specify an additional Servlet "JerseyJaxrsConfig":

```
<servlet>
  <display-name>Rest Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>RestServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>com.myprojectapp.rest;com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.listing</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <init-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
    <param- value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.LoggingFilter;com.myprojectapp.authentication.SecurityFilter</param-value>
  </init-param>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>api.version</param-name>
      <param-value>1.0.0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>swagger.api.basepath</param-name>
      <param-value>http://localhost:8002/MyProjectApp/api</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

If I start Tomcat 7, I get the following ClassNotFoundException:

> SEVERE: Servlet /MyProjectApp threw load() exception
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: **com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config.JerseyJaxrsConfig**
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:527)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:509)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:137)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1144)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1088)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5176)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5460)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

The weird thing is, that the servlet class "JerseyJaxrsConfig" already exists in one of the three recently downloaded jar files. So Eclipse is able to make a suggestion with this class when I type com.wordnik.swagger.jersey.config. But Tomcat is not able to find it on startup. Why? If I comment out the servlet "JerseyJaxrsConfig" in Web.xml then Tomcat runs with no errors. I tried several things like disabling my Quartz Job which starts with Tomcat, tried with other swagger versions or adding additional settings in Web.xml but with no success.

My environment is the following
 - Eclipse with Maven
 - Jersey 1.81.1
 - Java EE 7
 - Tomcat 7
 - Swagger 1.3

I appreciate your help.

Comment: whatdid you do to fix this issue?

Comment: you can solve your problem by this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18702049/how-to-add-jerseyjaxrsconfig-class-to-grizzly-as-servlet

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you can add the annotations without compile-time errors but with runtime errors when running Tomcat could be because the jars are present in your projects class-path, but missing in the WebContent/WEB-INF/lib-directory.

Copy the jars to that directory and it will probably work. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure add these libs:

```
swagger-annotations-1.3.10.jar
swagger-core_2.10-1.3.10.jar
swagger-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.10.jar
swagger-jersey2-jaxrs_2.10-1.3.10.jar
```

you should have all four jars with specified version.